# Need to get the min startdate and max enddate when there are no breaks in months or changes in ownership

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, overlap, minmax

I have a table that contains account ownership with startdates and enddates by account, however, some accounts have duplications and some have rules that overlap date ranges. I need a clean result set showing account, owner, startdate and enddate with no duplications or overlaps.
The source table look like this:

| accountnumber | startdate | enddate | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/2012 | 6/30/2012 | john |
| 1 | 3/1/2012 | 6/30/2012 | john |
| 1 | 5/31/2012 | 7/31/2015 | john |
| 2 | 5/1/2012 | 8/1/2012 | bill |
| 2 | 8/2/2012 | 10/31/2012 | bill |
| 2 | 12/1/2012 | 12/31/2012 | joe |
| 2 | 1/1/2013 | 12/31/2025 | bill |

I need the results to read like

| accountnumber | startdate | enddate | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/2012 | 7/31/2015 | john |
| 2 | 5/1/2012 | 10/31/2012 | bill |
| 2 | 12/1/2012 | 12/31/2012 | joe |
| 2 | 1/1/2013 | 12/31/2025 | bill |

Any help is much appreciated. I'm very much a novice when it comes to SQL.

Select Distinct removes my duplicates, but I still end up with multiple overlapping date ranges.

I don't know what version of sql server we are using. It is a connector within a BI application called Sisense, and doesn't really say.

This is my select statement so far:

```
    select distinct
    r.accountnumber,
    r.startdate,
    r.enddate,
    a.employeename Owner
    from "dbo"."ruleset" r
    left join "dbo"."rule" a on r.id = a.rulesetid
    where 
    a.roleid = '1' and
    r.isapproved = 'true'
```

Comment: What have you tried? what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Edited the original comment with the select statement I have. I'm new to SQL. I'm not sure which version. It's a connector within a BI application called Sisense. I assume it's the newest, but I don't see the version in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: A few comments: to get version, run `SELECT @@VERSION;`, with your last `WHERE` clause you lost the outer join (meaning you'll only be getting records which have a match in both tables), if that's not intended, you'll want to switch that.

Answer (score 0):

The table structure is a bit interesting, and while there may be a better way to figure this out with less code (i.e., set based); this does the trick. Here's my explanation along with my code.

**Thought Process**: I needed to order the rows in order of AccountNumber and Owner and identify whenever either of these change, as that would mark a new "term"; additionally I would need a way of marking the beginnings of each of these "terms". For the former I used `ROW_NUMBER`, and for the latter I used `LAG`. These records , along with with 2 new fields are inserted into a temp table.
Having these 2 pieces of information allowed for me to loop through the rows using a `WHILE` loop, keeping track of the current row, as well as the most recent beginning of a term. I update the first record of each term with the latest end date (assuming that you don't have earlier end dates for later start dates), and once we're done we select just the records which are marked as being the new term, and we get the result set which you asked for.

> Links to documentation.
> [RowNumber()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
> [Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
> [While](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Code example**:

```
DECLARE  @RowNumber INTEGER
        ,@BeginTerm INTEGER
        ,@EndDate DATE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OwnershipChange;
SELECT
    
     r.accountNumber    
    ,r.startDate    
    ,r.endDate  
    ,a.employeename AS [owner]
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY r.accountNumber, r.StartDate) RowNumber
    ,0 AS Processed
    ,CASE 
        WHEN a.employeename = LAG(a.employeename,1,NULL) OVER(ORDER BY r.accountNumber) 
            AND r.accountNumber = LAG(r.accountNumber,1,NULL)OVER(ORDER BY r.accountNumber) 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END AS NewOwnership
INTO #OwnershipChange
FROM dbo.ruleset r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.rule a ON r.id = a.rulesetid
WHERE a.roleid = '1' 
AND r.isapproved = 'true';

WHILE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1/0 
    FROM #OwnershipChange 
    WHERE Processed = 0
)
BEGIN
    SET @RowNumber = (
        SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber 
        FROM #OwnershipChange 
        WHERE Processed = 0
        ORDER BY RowNumber
    );
    SET @BeginTerm = (
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN NewOwnership = 1 THEN @RowNumber 
        ELSE @BeginTerm
    END 
    FROM #OwnershipChange
    WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber
    );
    SET @EndDate = (
        SELECT endDate
        FROM #OwnershipChange 
        WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber
    );

    UPDATE #OwnershipChange
    SET endDate = @EndDate
    WHERE RowNumber = @BeginTerm;

    UPDATE #OwnershipChange
    SET Processed = 1
    WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber;
END;

SELECT 
     accountNumber  
    ,startDate  
    ,endDate    
    ,[owner]
FROM #OwnershipChange
WHERE NewOwnership = 1;
```

Comment: @EmbassyCrew - does this meet your needs?